# Getting a null reference on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use RecyclerView and its adapter in a fragment. Whenever I try to open that fragment app crashes and throws an exception:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

MyActivity.java:

```java
public class upperClass extends ... {
    ...
    public static innerClass extends CorrectedPreferenceFragment ... {
         private RecyclerView  groupsInCommonRecyclerView;
         private View          v;    
         ...

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipient_common_groups,     container, false);

          groupsInCommonRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
          groupsInCommonRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


          ArrayList<GroupsInCommonItem> commonGroups = initializeGroupsInCommon();

          GroupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter groupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter = new GroupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter(getContext(), commonGroups);

          groupsInCommonRecyclerView.setAdapter(groupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter);

          return v;
        }          
    }
```

recipient_common_groups.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you do in `initializeGroupsInCommon()` method ?

Comment: why are you declaring inner class as static ?

Comment: Populating List with dummy data. @VivekMishra

Comment: The static keyword is the culprit

Answer (score 1):

Seems that groupsInCommonRecyclerView becomes null somewhere after setting layout manager and before setting adapter. Not obvious from posted code, so try going through your code with debugger step by step.

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` sometimes return null. So I suggest you to override `onAttach()` in fragment to get the context.
This means your layout manager is null because of null context and is not provided to the recyclerview .So while setting the adapter it throws the exception.
Try this and post the update of working status.

```
public class upperClass extends ... {
    ...
    public static innerClass extends CorrectedPreferenceFragment ... {
         private RecyclerView  groupsInCommonRecyclerView;
         private View          v;   
         private Context c;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context c) {
        super.onAttach(c);
        this.c = c; //this is one of the best way to get context of the activity to which the particular activity is associated with
      }
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipient_common_groups,     container, false);

          groupsInCommonRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

       LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
          lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
          groupsInCommonRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
          ArrayList<GroupsInCommonItem> commonGroups = initializeGroupsInCommon();
          GroupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter groupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter = new GroupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter(c, commonGroups);

          groupsInCommonRecyclerView.setAdapter(groupsInCommonRecycleViewAdapter);

          return v;
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not bind your recyclerview in activity by using findViewById... 
Please check.